# Vim: how to count indent from the beginning of the line

Tags: javascript, vim, vue.js

I'm working with JS file and when I type:

```
function() {
    some_code // it correctly indents this line
```

but when I have something like this:

```
productEditModal: function(product, i) {
                      some_code // new line starts from here
```

What I want is:

```
productEditModal: function(product, i) {
    some_code // new line should start from here
```

I tried several js-indent plugins but without success. My JS code is written inside .vue component file so maybe this is the reason plugins didn't work correct for me. Any advice would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set filetype to javascript. Inside your file write:

```
:set autoindent
:set filetype=javascript
```

Plugins associated with .vue files probably won't work, but it's worth a try.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I tried but it didn't work. I get same indent.

Also, if I type :filetype i get this:
filetype detection:ON  plugin:ON  indent:OFF

Comment: try to activate it: `:filetype plugin indent on`

Comment: still same issue... I tried to install js indent plugin https://github.com/pangloss/vim-javascript and visually it seems to be working (code is highlighted correctly), but not with indents.